# How to see the HTML reports Gradle generates in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have a Jenkins CI server running on a Linux VM. Jenkins runs Gradle task (build) and tests for my project.

I know the HTML reports for test results are generated in `project/build/reports` folders.

Is there way to see these reports using Jenkins?  Or, when the build failed, can the notification email include the link to this report?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) to archive the reports in Jenkins.

Add the "Publish HTML reports" post-build action, enter the directory containing your reports and specify the index page.

A link to the report will be displayed on the job's page and you can include the link in a mail, e.g. http://localhost:8080/job/my-job/Tests/

[image]

Comment: How do you get access to the old HTML reports? I see the option "Keep past HTML reports", but I checked this option and I keep seeing only the last report

Comment: The Pipeline DSL: `publishHTML([reportDir: 'build/reports/tests/test', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'HTML Report'])`

Comment: Further to @MarkHu's valuable answer, there are additional options now required (I'm using [HTML Publisher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/) plugin Version 1.31). Easiest way to get all the correct options is via `<JENKINS-URL>/pipeline-syntax/` as hinted to on the plugin home page.